# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY Error on Order Items deletion, for System Administrator profile

Tags: salesforce, apex, sharing, dml

Even though I have a System Administrator profile assigned to me, and have the CRUD permissions on the Order Line Item Object, I am receiving the below error when I try to delete the Order Item records through DML Operation in my apex class.

```
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8022M00000ANsKKQA1; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
```

I have written the Apex Class as **"Without sharing"** to avoid any conflict related to sharing rules. But still, I am receiving this error. Can anyone please let me know why this may be happening. I am calling this class from an ****after update** trigger** Also, I am inserting customer history records using the same class too. The apex class is as below.

```
public without sharing class LineItemHistoryRecordCreation {
    public LineItemHistoryRecordCreation() {}

    public void createLineItemHistoryRecord(List<OrderItem> ordItemList) {
        List<Id> oliIdList = new List<Id>();

        List<History__c> historyList = new List<History__c>();
        for(OrderItem oli : ordItemList) {
            oliIdList.add(oli.Id);

            History__c his          = new History__c();
            his.Change_Log__c       = 'Order Product record deleted-OrderNumber ' + oli.OrderId + '-' + oli.Id + '-' + oli.OB_Order_ID__c;
            his.History_Type__c     = 'Order Product-Deleted';
            his.History_DateTime__c = DateTime.now();
            his.Record_Name__c      = oli.Id;
            his.Prior_Value__c        = 'Active';
            his.New_Value__c        = 'Deleted';
            historyList.add(his);
        }

        insert historyList;

        List<OrderItem> oliList = [SELECT Id FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :oliIdList];

        System.debug('order List akki' + oliList);
        if(!oliList.isEmpty()) {
            delete oliList;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with understanding and solving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link

You need to set Status as Draft

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218993/insufficient-access-or-readonly-when-deleting-orderitems-in-apex